# Google Analytics: Find external sites which referred most visitors to a Goal

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, statistics

I have a goal setup in Google Analytics, I would like to track the number of visits that come from external sources.

e.g. I would like to see how many visits come from google.co.uk vs google.ie

Answer (score 3):

You should just need to use the "Traffic Sources" reports to get this.

Comment: And then click the little `Goal` tab on that report to see visits from that source pertinent to that Goal.